# IOS i make a CustomView in ViewController . when scroll it that was very slow

Tags: ios, uiview, draw, layer

i put a custom view on a controller ,the custom view's height is very high.
then when i scroll the controller that was very slow

Test environment:IOS5.0+,ipod touch

customView:

```
 @interface UICommonView : UIView
    //.....
 @end

 @implementation UICommonView
 //.....
 -(void)setBorder:(CGFloat)width color:(UIColor*)color
 {
     self.frameColor = color;
     self.frameWidth = width;
     [self.layer setBorderWidth:width];  
     [self.layer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];  
 }
 -(void)makeShadow
 {
     self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
     self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f,3.0f);
     self.layer.shadowColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
 }
 -(void)makeCornerRadius:(CGFloat)_cornerRadius
{
    self.cornerRadius = _cornerRadius;
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:_cornerRadius];
 }
 @end
```

controller:

```
//contentView is UICommonView  
//scrollView is UIScrollView on controller

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self.contentView makeShadow];
     [self.contentView makeCornerRadius:5.0f];
     [self.contentView setBorder:4.0f color:[UIColor white]];
     // self.contentView.backgroundColor = //......
     [self.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,1200)];
     [self.scrollView addSubview:contentView];
     scrollerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,1300);
     //add other view
     //I tested, only custom View impact speed
}
```

How to optimize it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadows are usually more efficient if you give them a path to follow:

```
-(void)makeShadow
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.layer.bounds cornerRadius:self.cornerRadius];
    self.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath; 
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f,3.0f);
    self.layer.shadowColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
}
```

However, because you are referencing both the rect and the corner radius of the view, you should call `[self makeShadow]` in both the

`-(void)makeCornerRadius:(CGFloat)_cornerRadius`

as well as within

```
-(void)setFrame
```

That way, whenever the frame or corner radius is changed, the shadow will update accordingly. This should give you smoother performance.